<p-tabPanel> not being projected into PrimeNG <p-tabView> using <ng-content>
I want to create an Angular component which consists of a set of tabs, the first one is always present, but then the rest of the tabs can vary. So I decided to create a component BaseTabView which defines the first tab, and then use <ng-content> so that the child component which inheritates from this component can add some extra tabs. This is what my base component looks like:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-base-tab-view',
      template: `
        <p-tabView>
          <p-tabPanel header="Common Tab">
            <div>Content for the common tab</div>
          </p-tabPanel>
          <ng-content></ng-content>
        </p-tabView>
      `,
    })
    export class BaseTabViewComponent {}

then the child ChildTabViewComponent component, which inherits from this component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-tab-view',
  template: `
    <app-base-tab-view>
      <p-tabPanel header="Child Tab 1">
        <div>Content for Child Tab 1</div>
      </p-tabPanel>
      <p-tabPanel header="Child Tab 2">
        <div>Content for Child Tab 2</div>
      </p-tabPanel>
    </app-base-tab-view>
  `,
})
export class ChildTabViewComponent extends BaseTabViewComponent {
 constructor() {
   super();
 }
}

But when I insert my child component in my template, only the common tab gets displayed.
In the console, get this error:
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[TabView -> TabView -> TabView]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for TabView!

Although TabViewModule is correctly imported in app.modules.ts.

Which Angular and PrimeNG you are using? Have you tried importing TabViewModule instead of TabView?

@YongShun Angular v11.0.9, PrimeNG v11.2.0. Yes, I'm actually doing that.
